Is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\{n!\sum_{k=1}^{n!}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right\}$ not convergent?

I need to calculate the limit (if it exist) $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\{n!\sum_{k=1}^{n!}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right\}$$ where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$, $n!$ is the factorial of $n$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

We have $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n!}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}}=H^{(\frac{3}{2})}_{n!}$$ where $H^{(r)}_{n}$ is the generalized harmonic number. So we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\{n!\sum_{k=1}^{n!}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right\}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\{n!H^{(\frac{3}{2})}_{n!}\right\}$$
I have observed the behavior of the fractional part using Wolfram Alpha. The plot shows that $\left\{n!H^{(\frac{3}{2})}_{n!}\right\}$ oscillates between $y=0$ and $y=1$. So my gut feeling is that the sequence $\left\{n!H^{(\frac{3}{2})}_{n!}\right\}$ is not convergent. Also we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n!}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}}-\sum_{k=n!+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
So we have $$n!\sum_{k=1}^{n!}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}}=n!\ \zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-n!\sum_{k=n!+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
where $\zeta(s)$ denotes the Riemann zeta function. Now denote
$$a_n=n!\sum_{k=1}^{n!}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
So if the sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is convergent, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left\{a_n\right\}=l $$
So we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left\{a_{n+1}\right\}=l $$
Now $$e^{2\pi i a_n}=e^{2\pi i \left\{a_n\right\}}$$
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left\{a_n\right\}=l$, so we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{2\pi i a_n}=e^{2\pi i l}$$ and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{2\pi i a_{n+1}}=e^{2\pi i l}$$ So by dividing the above equations we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{2\pi i (a_{n+1}-a_{n})}=1$$
Now we have
$$a_{n+1}=(n+1)!\sum_{k=1}^{(n+1)!}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$
Sorry but I don't have any nice ideas. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.
Edit: We can express the sum in terms of the Hurwitz zeta function:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n!}\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}=\zeta(3/2)-\zeta(3/2,n!+1)
$$ and the asymptotic behavior, as $n \to \infty$, is given by
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n!}\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}= \zeta(3/2)-\frac{2}{\sqrt{n!+1}}-\frac12 \frac1{(n!+1)^{3/2}}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac1{(n!)^{5/2}}\right)
$$
(see the link above). We would obtain the same result with the Euler-Maclaurin formula.
So we have $$
a_n= n! \sum_{k=1}^{n!}\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}= n!\ \zeta(3/2)-\frac{2 n!}{\sqrt{n!+1}}-\frac{n!}{2} \frac1{(n!+1)^{3/2}}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac1{(n!)^{3/2}}\right)
$$
Hence we obtain
$$
a_n=n!\ \zeta(3/2)-\frac{2\sqrt{n!} }{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n!}}}-\frac{1}{2 (n!)^{1/2}} \frac1{(1+\frac{1}{n!})^{3/2}}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac1{(n!)^{3/2}}\right)
$$
So we obtain an asymptotic expansion of $a_n$ as $n\to\infty$, $$a_n\sim  n!\ \zeta(3/2)-\frac{2\sqrt{n!} }{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n!}}}$$
So we have $$\{a_n\}=\left\{ n!\ \zeta(3/2)-\frac{2\sqrt{n!} }{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n!}}}-\frac{1}{2 (n!)^{1/2}} \frac1{(1+\frac{1}{n!})^{3/2}}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac1{(n!)^{3/2}}\right)\right\} $$

Please try to avoid titles that consist of only MathJax code, as they break some navigational shortcuts.

@ArturoMagidin Thanks. I will keep this in mind. Can you please do this so that I can learn how do it.

Isn't $\sum_{k\ge 1} 1/k^{3/2}=\zeta(3/2) = 2.61237\ldots$ just a constant?

@R.J.Mathar Yes, but we have a fractional part as well.

edited the title.  Note that the $n!$   is most likely a red herring, unless  replacing it with simple $n$ (in both location) itself gives something without a limit

@WillJagy Thanks. So is the sequence not convergent?

Too long for a comment.
As @Will Jagy commented, forget the red herring and use $n$ instead of $n!$.
I think that you made a mistake. Using, as you did
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}=H_n^{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$
Defining (as you did)
$$a_n=n \,H_n^{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$
$$\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)\, H_{n+1}^{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}}{
   n\, H_n^{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}}=1+\frac 1n+\frac 1{n^{3/2}\, \zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}\right) }+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
The sequence is not convergent.

$(+1)$ Thank you. How does this gives that the sequence of fractional part ${a_n}$ is not convergent?

@Max  $a_n\sim  n \zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-2\sqrt n$

Yes but I need to find whether the fractional part of $a_n$ that is ${a_n}$ is convergent or not.

NOT AN ANSWER...
Set $$a_n (s) := n! \sum_{k=1}^{n!} k^{-s} \qquad \tilde{a}_n (s) :=n \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{-s} ~.$$
For any $s \ge 2$ we know $\{ a_n(s) \}$ converges if $\zeta(s)$ is rational (I made a mistake in this line that I removed now). However, for $s\ge2$ we also know $\{ \tilde{a}_n (s) \}$ converges if and only if $\zeta(s)$ is an integer. Therefore $\{ \tilde{a}_n (s) \}$ diverges for any $s\ge2$. This is proven in a few lines with the Euler-Maclaurin formula (I will omit the details here for now ).
If $\{ \tilde{a}_n (s) \}$ converges then trivialy $\{ a_n(s) \}$ also converges.
I expect that $\{a_n (3/2) \}$ diverges, hence we can not dircetly use the convergence properties of $\{ \tilde{a}_n (3/2) \}$. One could use information about the limit points of $\{ \tilde{a}_n (3/2) \}$, but I expect this approach to fail, because the sequence is problably dense in $[0,1]$.
Another idea is it to expand $\zeta (s)$ as a sum of factorials. There are surely well known theorems for this. One that I remember is: any real number $x$ can be expressed as $$x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \cdot n! + \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \frac{b_n}{(-n+1)!}$$ with $0\le b_i \le |i|$ and $b_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all integers $i$. There are exactly two ways of expanding an integer in this form and exactly one expansion for every other real number. Let $c_n (s)$ be the coefficients of the expansion of $\zeta(s)$. Then $$n! \zeta (s) = \underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k(s) k! n! + \sum_{k=-n+1}^{-1} c_k(s) \frac{n!}{(-k+1)!}}_{\in \mathbb{Z}} + \sum_{-\infty}^{-n} \frac{c_k(s) n!}{(-k+1)!}~.$$
Hence we have $$\{n! \zeta(s) \} = \{\frac{c_{-n}(s)}{n+1} + \frac{c_{-n-1}(s)}{(n+1)(n+2)} + ...\}$$
The point I want to make is that we need some information about $\zeta(3/2)$ to proof that the given sequence diverges.

$(+1)$. Thanks for the nice idea. I think you are almost there .I am expecting that you can actually solve the question. Please let me know if anything comes up. Thank you!

Please write $c_{-n}(s)$ explicitly. Thanks.
